# Workflow staus values - how to find the numeric value of a manually defined custom workflow status?

Tags: workflow, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, workflow-variable

I have a long and complex workflow with many stages and steps written in SharePoint Designer 2013. The workflow is associated with a SharePoint library that was published from a form designed in InfoPath Designer 2013. I need the form to respond to combinations of active user and workflow status.

**I have manually set the workflow status to descriptive names, i.e. 'QM Review', throughout the workflow.** This was done using the `Set Workflow Status to [STRING]` action.

I have added the data connection to get the workflow status but I understand that the value returned is numeric. How do I find out the numeric value attributed to my descriptive status names? Or, how do I define a numeric value for these status names?

Comment: Try creating a view that includes the workflow status and switching to DataSheet view.

Comment: Thanks for this - I created a view that retrieved all the variables I could from the workflow data connection. This lead to me finding the string I wanted. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no need to reference numeric values only in InfoPath Designer 2013 in this example. From the managed data connection to the workflow (here named AccTestJanuray2016), the `Description` property:

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1qd9.jpg)

is returned as a `string` that corresponds directly to the Workflow status that is set in the SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow by using the `Set Workflow Status to [STRING]` action.